# Laravel create project not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

Am running laravel create project in windows command prompt like,  `composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel-medium --prefer-dist` but am getting error like,

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>   Your configuration does not allow connections to http://packagist.org/packa
>   ges.json. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.

i don't know how to fix this issue. Please help me.

Comment: What have you tried to debug this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a discussion about this [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/47jc25/todays_composer_release_04a1085d_breaks_https/).

You can try to run `composer self-update`. This will update your composer version and might solve the problem.

If it does not, you could turn ssl off, by running `composer config -g secure-http false`, however I would not recommend this.